# Pivot Table returning Null value in output

Tags: mysql, pivot

I am trying to get a single row for each 'resp_id', with another 2 columns beside it. However, only one output is shown while the other keeps showing a null value.

```
SELECT `resp_id`,
    CASE 
        WHEN survey.`var`='quality' 
        THEN survey.`val`
        ELSE NULL    
    END
AS `quality`,
    CASE 
        WHEN survey.`var`='receive_menu' 
        THEN survey.`val`
        ELSE NULL 
    END
AS `receive_menu`
FROM survey
GROUP BY survey.`resp_id`;
```

Output (Sample):

[image]

Sample of sourcefile:

[image]

I have also tried to play around but only the value inside the 'quality' column is shown but not the rest. Are there any reasons it does not work?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, you just need to add `GROUP_CONCAT()` or `SUM()` to make it work:

```
SELECT `resp_id`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE 
        WHEN survey.`var`='quality' 
        THEN survey.`val`
    END)
AS `quality`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE 
        WHEN survey.`var`='receive_menu' 
        THEN survey.`val`
    END)
AS `receive_menu`
FROM survey
GROUP BY survey.`resp_id`;
```

I removed `ELSE NULL` from the `CASE` expression because it's already returning `NULL` by default. Use `ELSE` only when you want to return something else than `NULL`.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QpDVZCwJ)

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much, it works, ill read up on the GROUP_CONCAT function more, thank you :')